# load view from another controller

Tags: ios5

I have multiple view in storyboard with individual controllers in my code.

view1 - ViewController1

view2 - ViewController2

view3 - ViewController3

I want to call view3 from ViewController2.

- loadAnotherView 
  {
  NSLog(@"loadAnotherView");

  // code to load another view

}

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do it, put a reference to `ViewController3` into `ViewController2` and then call it's `view` method.

It's not a good thing to do,though, because view controllers are supposed to manage their own views, not load a view from another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines of code, maybe they help you.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
ViewControllerName *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

[self presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

normally there is a specific method that you can use when working with the Storyboard which helps you to switch to another viewcontroller. It should be more comfortable than the first lines of code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
        MenuTableViewController *mtvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    }    
}
```